# How can I track how many installed application is using GPS locations

Tags: android, gps

I have a requirement where I have to track GPS data. Which installed application is using GPS and when means Date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to get a list of installed packages (by invoking a [getInstalledPackages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29) method) and then use `permission` attribute on each [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) element to determine thenever or not location permissions are set.

But this method can't give you information about when it was used, and was it used at all. IT can just give you an information is this app **can** use GPS